# how to get existing table using snowflake sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my snowflake db, I have already created tables. I used the sqlalchemy inspector library to check if it was created.

```py
engine = create_engine("snowflake://my_connection_string")
db = {}
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
inspector = inspect(engine)
schemas = inspector.get_schema_names()
for schema in schemas:
    print(f"schema: {schema}")
    for table_name in inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema):
        print(f"table name: {table_name}")
        db[f"{schema}.{table_name}"] = Table(f"{schema}.{table_name}", metadata)
        print("Columns: ", end=': ')
        for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name, schema=schema):
            print(f"{column['name']}", end=',')
        print()
```

However, I'm having trouble fetching those tables using sqlalchemy metadata:

```py
engine = create_engine("snowflake://my_connection_string")

meta_data = MetaData(bind=engine)
MetaData.reflect(meta_data)
```

when I run the above code I get the following error:

```py
ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001059 (22023): SQL compilation error:
Must specify the full search path starting from database for TEST_DB
[SQL: SHOW /* sqlalchemy:_get_schema_primary_keys */PRIMARY KEYS IN SCHEMA test_db]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is "TEST_DB" your database or schema name? The error comes when the connector tries to execute the command `SHOW /* sqlalchemy:_get_schema_primary_keys */PRIMARY KEYS IN SCHEMA TEST_DB` in Snowflake, but fails because it cannot find the schema with that name. I suggest checking if in your engine you use the correct DB name, and your username that you use in the connector has the privileges in the selected db and schemas

Comment: @aek I added schema="public" and it works fine now! Thank you!

Comment: Great! It looks like the issue was with the default place where your script started to iterate the objects.

Comment: Could you update the question with the working answer? It's not clear where `schema="public"` should be added. Thanks!